# How to transform semicolon separated strings of column names and values into a new table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am relatively new to Snowflake and struggle a bit with setting up a transformation for a semi-structured dataset. I have several log data batches, where each batch (table row in Snowflake) has the following columns: LOG_ID, COLUMN_NAMES, and LOG_ENTRIES .

COLUMN_NAMES contains a semicolon-separated list of columns names, e.g.:

> “TIMESTAMP;Sensor A;Sensor B”, “TIMESTAMP;Sensor B;Sensor C”

LOG_ENTRIES:entry contains a semicolon separated list of values, e.g.

> “2020-02-11 09:08:19; 99.24;12.25”

The COLUMN_NAMES string can be different between log batches (Snowflake rows), but the names in the order they appear describe the content of the LOG_ENTRIES column values of the same row. My goal is to transform the data into a table that has column names for all unique values present in the COLUMN_NAMES column, e.g.:

| LOG_ID | TIMESTAMP | Sensor A | Sensor B | Sensor C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-11 09:08:19 | 99.24 | 12.25 | NaN |
| 2 | 2020-02-11 09:10:44 | NaN | 13.32 | 0.947 |

Can this be achieved with a snowflake script, and if so, how? :)

Best regards,
Johan

Comment: is there a defined number of columns that appear in COLUMN_NAMES?  And will there always be only 2 sensors in a record?

Comment: Hi! No, unfortunately both the names, and number of columns/sensors can very with each record. (Some columns are present in almost all record, while others are more rare...). Thanks a lot for your proposed solution by the way, is it compatible with varying number/name of columns, as described?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **SPLIT_TO_TABLE** function, split the two values, and join them by index.
After that, all you have to do is use **PIVOT** to invert the table.

Sample data:

```
create or replace table splittable (LOG_ID int, COLUMN_NAMES varchar, LOG_ENTRIES varchar);
insert into splittable (LOG_ID, COLUMN_NAMES, LOG_ENTRIES) 
values (1, 'TIMESTAMP;Sensor A;Sensor B', '2020-02-11 09:08:19;99.24;12.25'), 
       (2, 'TIMESTAMP;Sensor B;Sensor C', '2020-02-11 09:10:44;13.32;0.947');
```

Solution proposal:

```
WITH src AS (
  select LOG_ID, cn.VALUE as COLUMN_NAMES, le.VALUE as LOG_ENTRIES 
      from splittable as st, 
      lateral split_to_table(st.COLUMN_NAMES, ';') as cn,
      lateral split_to_table(st.LOG_ENTRIES, ';') as le
    where cn.INDEX = le.INDEX
)  
select * from src 
pivot (min(LOG_ENTRIES) for COLUMN_NAMES in ('TIMESTAMP','Sensor A','Sensor B','Sensor C'))
order by LOG_ID;
```

Reference: [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html), [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html)

If the column list is variable and you can't define it then you have to write some generator, maybe it will help: [CREATE A DYNAMIC PIVOT IN SNOWFLAKE](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-a-dynamic-PIVOT-in-Snowflake)

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the data into an ACTUAL semi-structured data type that you can then natively query using Snowflake SQL.

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT column_names, log_entries
FROM (VALUES ('TIMESTAMP_;SENSOR1','2021-02-01'||';1.2')) x (column_names, log_entries)
),
y AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM x,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => split(column_names,';')) f
),
z AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM x,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => split(log_entries,';')) f
)
SELECT listagg(('"'||y.value||'":"'||z.value||'"'),',') as cnt
     , parse_json('{'||cnt||'}') as var
FROM y
JOIN z
  ON y.seq = z.seq
 AND y.index = z.index
GROUP BY y.seq;
```